# How do I mount an NTFS partition in /etc/fstab and prevent files/directories from receiving exec permissions when they're created?

Tags: linux, permissions, fstab, ntfs

I have an NTFS partition that I want to mount using `/etc/fstab`. I don't want any files to have executable permissions on this drive, so I wrote the following rule:

```
/dev/sda2 /media/sharedfolder ntfs auto,user,noatime,noexec,rw,async 0 0
```

However, I don't believe this will prevent files from being created with executable permissions. It will simply prevent them from being executed. Perhaps this is fine, but is it possible to remove all executable permissions from newly created files on this partition using an `/etc/fstab` rule?

Would using `umask` and `fmask` be enough, like this rule?

```
/dev/sda2 /media/sharedfolder ntfs auto,user,noatime,noexec,rw,async,umask=0111, 0 0
```

I'm unsure because Wikipedia lists `umask` as an option specific to the [FAT filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab#fat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia isn't as good a reference as the man page. Both the the traditional [`ntfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) driver and the now-preferred [ntfs-3g](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g) support the `umask` option.

You shouldn't set `umask` to exclude executable permissions on directories, though, since you can't access files inside a non-executable directory. Instead, use separate values for `fmask=0111` (non-directories) and `dmask=0777` (directories) (you can omit this one since all bits allowed is the default value).

Comment: Is `ntfs-3g` preferred because it's a newer driver (and therefore I would assume has better support, more stability, etc.)? I added `fmask=0111` to my options list, and once I remount the partition with `mount -a`, files created shouldn't be executable when created, correct?

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano ntfs-3g has at least better write support, I don't know the details. `mount -a` doesn't have any effect if the filesystem is already mounted, you need to unmount it first or run `mount -o remount,fmask=0111,… /mount/point`.

Comment: The addition of `fmask` does just what I need, and thank you for the additional `mount` command as well.